# Solving $yy''+ky'^2-k=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, geodesic

During some calculations about geodesics, after some simplification I found the following Cauchy problem:

$$yy''+ky'^2-k=0$$
$$y(0)=1,y'(0)=c$$

with $c>1$ and $0<k<1$.

How could I solve it?

If  $k=1$ then I could use 
$$(yy')'=y'^2+yy''$$
is there any similar substitution in the case $k\neq1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transform into $yy''=k(1-y'^2)$ and then into the separated form
$$
\frac{y'y''}{1-y'^2}=k\frac{y'}{y}
$$